# Linux open file dialog

Tags: c, linux, file

Im trying to program a open file dialog in C. I dont want to use any gui projects.

It seems there's XORG and wayland so I'm guessing I need to implement open file dialog for both of those.

So far my program looks like this

```
#ifdef _WIN32

        OPENFILENAME  ofd;        
        memset(&ofd,0,sizeof(ofd));
        ofd.lStructSize     = sizeof(ofd);
        ofd.lpstrFile       = filename;
        ofd.nMaxFile        = MAX_PATH;
        ofd.Flags           = OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST;
    #endif

#ifdef __linux__
        
#endif
```

Comment: You're not likely to find anything. This is complex, since you have to write your own functions for scanning the directories, then all the low-level window operations. It's way too big to answer in an SO question.

Comment: Linux as such is just the core of a system. Any graphical user system is an addition. So you will not find any Linux call that provides a file open dialog, or even a dialog at all. The X Window System that you found in X.org or Wayland is just one possible implementation. You might need to read its documentation to learn about its capabilities. Anyway, using X or any other graphical system incorporates the usage of libraries. -- If you come from Microsoft Windows, you might think that opening the Windows file selector can be done without library: I think you are wrong, each DLL is a library.